# C++ XOR operator precendence

Tags: c++, c

So I am confused here, does : 
 is

```
 a ^= b^c
```

equivalent to

```
 a = a ^ (b ^ c)
```

or is it `a = (a ^ b) ^ c`?

Comment: You know, *read the documentation*.

Comment: Did you try it out and see what the result is?

Comment: See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: It wouldn't even matter anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Any short form operator:

```
LHS OP= RHS;
```

works very much like:

```
LHS = LHS OP RHS;
```

As pointed out in comments, there are differences with the number of evaluations done and so on, so if you start to have side-effects in the evaluation of `LHS`, this simple equivalence is not so simple anymore. Or equivalent. Which is why I've re-worded the above to make it less iron-clad.

So it's the former, i.e. `a = a ^ (b ^ c)`.

Comment: @PaulR: what about it? `, c` is not part of the RHS of the xor-assignment in that expression, so LHS is `a`, RHS is `b` and unwind's equivalence holds except that there should be no semi-colon in it. More to the point, what about the questioner's expression? There, LHS is `a` and RHS is `b^c`, so according to this answer it's equivalent to `a = a ^ b^c`, but `^` associates left-to-right. You should write, `LHS = (LHS OP (RHS))`.

Comment: @SteveJessop The only way to match "a ^= b, c;" to the pattern "LHS OP= RHS;" is to match "b, c" to RHS. So Paul's pedantic point is accurate ... "LHS = LHS OP RHS;" is wrong and so is "LHS = LHS OP (RHS);"

Comment: This is incorrect for at least two reasons. One, “LHS OP= RHS” evaluates LHS once, but “LHS = LHS OP RHS” evaluates LHS twice. Two, it fails to preserve precedence; “a *= b+c” is not equivalent to “a = a * b+c”, because the former evaluates “b+c” first but the latter evaluates “a * b” first.

Comment: @Jim: *pedantically* it's neither inaccurate nor accurate, it's a question ;-p But sure, unwind's production is *not* the production used in the C or C++ grammar to define an assignment expression, and it cannot correctly parse C or C++.

Comment: @SteveJessop Now you're being pedantic; it's a question that makes a point. "it cannot correctly parse C or C++" -- and it's wrong.

Comment: @Jim: I know I'm being pedantic, that's why I said *pedantically*, and added a smiley-thing. If you're not in the mood, ignore that sentence. In the other one I agree with you. I'm pretty sure "wrong" is another way of saying "not correct", so I'm not sure how "and it's wrong" adds much to it not being correct.

Comment: Anyway, we sure are putting a lot of effort into a question with 7 downvotes. I'm getting a bit fed up with people who use SO as a substitute for a manual or tutorial or classroom.

Comment: @SteveJessop 'saying "not correct"' -- That's not actually what you wrote ... and I apparently misunderstood what you did write.

Answer (score 3):

"C and C++" covers a lot of ground, but taking one example, the C99 standard says (6.5.16.2):

> A compound assignment of the form `E1 op= E2` differs from the simple
>   assignment expression `E1 = E1 op (E2)` only in that the lvalue `E1` is
>   evaluated only once.

In C++, operator overloading means that the first expression might be equivalent to neither of the other two depending on the types of the operands. But for built-in compound operators the same rule applies. C++03 says (5.17/7):

> The behavior of an expression of the form `E1 op=  E2` is equivalent to
>   `E1  =  E1 op E2` except that `E1` is evaluated only once.

Note that only the C standard bothers to include the necessary parentheses to directly answer your question: it's nominally `a ^ (b ^ c)` rather than `(a ^ b) ^ c`.

But I think we can assume that in the ad hoc BNF-like grammatical language that the C++ standard is using here, a BNF-non-terminal such as `E2` is always considered to be a subexpression of the expression it appears in. So in a case with left-to-right associativity (and all of the operators with compound-assignment version associate left-to-right), which would split `E2` such that it's no longer a sub-expression, we must mentally insert enough parentheses to prevent that.

In practice it's not going to matter for XOR, since the values are the same anyway *unless* you generate a trap representation along the way, and that causes a fault. This could happen on a non-2's-complement implementation of C or C++, and an implementation for which that's the case could *not* compute `a ^= b^c` as `a = (a^b)^c` even if it wanted to. Non-2's-complement implementations are approximately non-existent, but the standard permits them.

Importantly, `a -= b - c` is *not* equivalent to `a = (a - b) - c` in the case where `a`, `b`, `c` are integers. Unless `c` is equal to `0`.

Answer (score 2):

Think about the XOR truth table, try it out, does it even matter?

```
x | y | XOR
-----------
0 | 0 |  0
1 | 0 |  1
0 | 1 |  1
1 | 1 |  0
```

So if you had say `b = 10; //1010` and `c = 7; //0111` and `a = 3; //0011`

```
b ^ c =     1010 ^ 0111 = 1101 
a ^ (b^c) = 0011 ^ 1101 = 1110 (14)


a ^ b =     0011 ^ 1010 = 1001
(a^b) ^c =  1001 ^ 0111 = 1110 (14)
```

Given your specific example, assuming no operator-overloading, and only using the associative XOR operator... it doesn't really matter.

Being a little less specific
`^=` is applied first, so:

`a ^= b^c` is equivalent to `a = a ^ (b^c)`

Comment: Question is about C++. It matters because `operator^` might be overloaded. It also matters because `^=` follows a general rule that applies to all assignment operators, not just associative ones.

Comment: @SteveJessop - The question has both C and C++ tags, the operator^ can't be overloaded if both tags apply. Also the question doesn’t have the Operator-overloading tag... so the logical assumption here is non-overloaded... but you are correct so I'll make the distinction.

Comment: I think you're right, the questioner isn't prepared for operator overloading, because if `operator^=` is overloaded then the first expression could be equivalent to neither of the other two. But I'm pretty sure that the question isn't *really* about the properties of XOR, it's intended to be about the interpretation of the compound assignment operator.

Comment: @SteveJessop - Yeah, I'll give you that one, I was going at it a little too literal perhaps. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no operator precedence here. Your question is about associativity, and as the operator is associative it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: How come there's no precedence here? The C standard quite unambiguously states that the precedence of `^` is higher than that of `^=`.

Comment: Actually, the answer requires attendance to both precedence and associativity. That it doesn't make any difference is because `^` is commutative.